'Something went wrong' install without a log (Ubuntu 24.10)
I've been trying to install Ubuntu 24.10 on my laptop. But, without error (pun intended), it always fails and if I try to open the installer again, it's just infinite 'Preparing Ubuntu...'
My laptop is:

Asus ROG STRIX G15 (2022)
AMD Ryzen™ 9 6900H with Radeon 680M integrated.
NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 3070 Ti Laptop.
Also, it's Optimus and MUX switch compatible.
Disk is partitioned with Windows 11 and a blank partition of 200gb for dual-booting Ubuntu.

I already installed Fedora and Linux mint successfully on this laptop, but neither satisfied me (Fedora is way too buggy with graphic drivers, and I prefer Gnome over Linux mint because of those sweet touchpad gestures.)
I was able to proceed with the installation in Ubuntu 24.10 before, but now it just doesn't work. I tried flashing with balenaEtcher, Ventoy, redownloading... Nothing works.
Before you ask, I do not have any more USB sticks.
Little help over here? I'm open to questions and helping others solve my problems.
Log from sudo ubuntu-bug ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap (supposedly):


UPDATE:
A poster helped me on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1gh7jk1/something_went_wrong_install_without_a_log_ubuntu/
and here's what I found out:
UPDATE:
I tried on my PC (not laptop) and the installer works fine, albeit a bit slow. Virtualbox too, so seems related to my laptop.
UPDATE 2: I tried installing with cable, airplane mode, everything. The installer crashes randomly.
Sometimes staying a few seconds and going for next screen crashes it.
Rushing through the installer crashes it when selecting on the "Drivers and Codecs" screen.
Sometimes it will not even got past the select language screen.

UPDATE 3 (Probably the last one):
I truly CANNOT believe what is happening. I disabled the dGPU, booted into live Linux and NOW there are errors on the subiquity installer log.
First time this happened and needed to reboot the laptop:

Second time AND THIS HAPPENED:

I'm truly baffled and I cannot understand anything. I'm probably going back to Linux Mint or giving up fully on Linux. It seems newer laptops with Optimus or whatever crap doesn't work well with this.
